# Unable to specify valueSerializer instance for Spring KafkaTemplate

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to set custom value serializer into Spring's **KafkaTemplate**. Value serializer looks like the following:
`JsonSerializer<JourneyMailExchange> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>(customObjectMapper);` (for example, in order to apply `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE`)

it can be easily done with KafkaProducer:

```
new KafkaProducer<>(properties, Serdes.String().serializer(), valueSerializer);
```

but I haven't found possibilities to do the same with `KafkaTemplate`. I see only     `props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);` property for `ProducerFactory`, but it's not what I'm looking for (not possible to provide specific instance).

We create KafkaTemplate in the following way:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs(kafkaProperties.getDefaultSettings()));
}

private static Map<String, Object> producerConfigs(Map<String, String> defaultSettings) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(defaultSettings);
    props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
    KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic("topicName");
    return kafkaTemplate;
}
```

Also found the following method:

```
kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter(customObjectMapper));
```

but it applies conversion only if we work with Spring's `Message` instance and ignore provided conversion if we invoke send methods with key and value.

spring-kafka version: 2.1.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured out, it's possible to do that with configuring multiple `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` by providing value serializer into constructor:

```
public DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(Map<String, Object> configs, Serializer<K> keySerializer,
        Serializer<V> valueSerializer)
```

final version for specific value serializer looks like the following (number of configured `ProducerFactory` is the same as number of required different value serializers):

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactoryWithSnakeCaseValueSerializer(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    Map<String, Object> props = producerConfigsWithSnakeCaseValueSerializer(kafkaProperties.getDefaultSettings());
    JsonSerializer<Object> valueSerializer = new JsonSerializer<>(createObjectMapper(SNAKE_CASE));
    valueSerializer.setAddTypeInfo(false);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props, Serdes.String().serializer(), valueSerializer);
}

private static Map<String, Object> producerConfigsWithSnakeCaseValueSerializer(Map<String, String> defaultSettings) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(defaultSettings);
    ...
    return props;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerConfigsWithSnakeCaseValueSerializer) {
    KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerConfigsWithSnakeCaseValueSerializer);
    kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic("topicName");
    return kafkaTemplate;
}
```